# Available approaches for layouts when only the navigation depends on the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Given a layout with a navigation bar which depends on the current controller :

```
# layout.html.slim
doctype html
html
  body
    main
      = render partial: 'domain_nav'
      = yield
```

The app has several business domains, let's say "Clients", "Tasks", "Books", with their own distinct navigations (`clients_nav`, `tasks_nav`, `books_nav`).

Each part has several controllers, and the view will display the navigation based on the controller business domain (e.g. the Clients::CompaniesController will display the `clients_nav`).

The html above is simplified but basically, all controllers share the same layout except for the `domain_nav` which depends on the domain.

I see several ways to handle that :

- use a helper and determine which nav to use based on the controller
  name : this means editing the helper each time a new controller is
  introduced, it doesn't feel right
- use `content_for :navigation` in each view and `yield :navigation` : since we're sure that the navigation is displayed for each view,
  this doesn't feel right either
- use a sub layout per section and call `render layout: 'clients/layout' do` : it works but then i18n becomes a mess
- define one layout per domain : not very DRY
- use a single layout and define which nav (partial name) to use in the controller : that partial name would be set using either
  inheritance (have one controller per domain that sets the nav partial
  name) or concerns
- define a layout per domain (setting the layout in each controller) but render them using a shared layout as shown below

---

```
# layouts/_shared.html.slim
doctype html
html
  body
    main
      = render partial: nav_path
      = yield

# layouts/clients.html.slim
= render partial: 'layouts/shared', locals: { nav_path: 'clients/nav' }

# layouts/tasks.html.slim
= render partial: 'layouts/shared', locals: { nav_path: 'tasks/nav' }

# layouts/books.html.slim
= render partial: 'layouts/shared', locals: { nav_path: 'books/nav' }
```

Are there other approaches to this problem ? Which one would you pick and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different way. Since it's the responsibility of the controller to decide of the layout, I thought it would be the rails way to let it also decide of the navigation.

So just like there is a "layout" declaration, I now have a "navigation" declaration. Here's what the controllers look like:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  navigation 'clients/nav'
  …
end

class BooksController < ApplicationController
  navigation 'books/nav'
  …
end
```

and I have just one layout:

```
doctype html
html
  body
    main
      = render partial: navigation
      = yield
```

The navigation method is declared in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :navigation

  def self.navigation(path)
    define_method :navigation do
      path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also use `controller_name`. It is included in the params and tells you which controller called the current view.

Comment: @hashrocket I chose not too intentionally. I feel like the controller should tell the view what to do, while using `controller_name` means letting the view guess what to do.

Comment: I completely understand. Just wanted to throw it out there as another option.

Comment: @hashrocket ok :)

Answer (score 1):

If controllers could be grouped by their namespace as like their navigation name, I will go with the `"use a helper and determine which nav to use based on the controller name"` approach. Like if a controller name starts with `Clients` (for example, `Clients::CompaniesController`) we could easily map it to `clients_nav`.

```
def nav_path
    if params[:controller].starts_with? "Client"
        'clients/nav'
    elsif params[:controller].starts_with? "Task"
        'tasks/nav'
    else
        'books/nav'
    end
end
```

If you cant group controllers by such namespace, you could still go with a different variation of this approach only if you have an admin panel. We could create a table which map `controller_name` to `navigation_path`. Entries on this table could be populated from admin panel only.

Comment: Not what I was looking for but still a decent solution, thanks for submitting it